# MATLAB sparse must be same length

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get an old Matlab script going. It comes from an old implementation of the minimum curvature gridding algorithm from here:

https://github.com/duncombe/matlab/blob/master/saga/

My problem occurs in the script uniquept.m on the line a = sparse(ind,1,f(:,jj));

https://github.com/duncombe/matlab/blob/master/saga/uniquept.m

```
     % Find unique points (rows in R)
[Ro,ind,c] = unique(R);
len = length(c);

 % Quick exit if no coincident points
if len==np,
  Ro = R; fo = f; return
end

 % Map values f to fo ...............
fo = zeros(len,dim_f);
for jj = 1:dim_f
  a = sparse(ind,1,f(:,jj));
  fo(:,jj) = full(a)./c;
end
```

The input are X, Y and Z values. For this function,
R = [X Y]
f = Z

ind = unique X,Y positions
f(:,jj) = f(:, 1) so all of the Z values

I am running Matlab 2022a, and this makes the number of X,Y positions less than the number of Z values. I assume it worked for the original author so did previous versions of Matlab's sparse function accept vectors of different lengths?

Comment: `unique(R)` does not give the unique rows in R, as the comment suggests. It gets all the unique values in the array. So it’s mixing x and y. This has not changed, so it is likely that the code has always been broken.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks. That would explain the severe difference in length between the "unique" XY locations (42,000) versus Z vector (150,000). And how it "reduced" 150,000 already unique XY to 42,000 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I need to add "rows" to the unique function call, and filter for corresponding Z values in the sparse call.

Edit: which means the unique function has probably changed since 1995 when this was written.

Comment: The unique function has never worked on rows by default. Either this code was always broken, or it was called with a different definition of `R`, or it had a “rows” in there that somehow got deleted.